# Can custom Material-UI components be tested with React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm evaluating widget toolkits for a new project, and I want to be sure that I can write unit tests for them first. So I've created a simple component using Material-UI based on react-autosuggest using axios to query a simple API. The component works just fine, but I can't seem to get it to work with React Testing Library.

The test is failing with this: "Cannot read property 'px' of undefined"

It almost seems as though Material-UI isn't loading fully, so the component can't be tested until it is. I have no previous experience with unit testing React components, but shouldn't it load in all the dependencies at the top of my component when it renders?

Here's a demo of my failure in Code Sandbox: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-material-ui-problem-ndn9f